# An idiomatic way to construct a tree in python from a list of locations / namespaces?

Tags: python, tree, namespaces

What is an idiomatic way to accomplish the following task in python? The algorithm does not have to be efficient or use constant memory.

Given the list of tuples `[("location", data)]`, for example:

```
from_this = [
    ("global.module1.submodule1.function1", "some data"),
    ("global.module1.func1", "other data"),
    ("global.module1.submodule1.func2", "data again"),
    ("global.module1.submodule1.func3", "data"),
    ("global.module2.func3", "data"),
    ("global.module4.submodule1.func3", "data"),
    ("global.module4.submodule2.func4", "daata"),
    ("global.module4.submodule2", "da_ta")
]
```

The goal is to construct a hierarchical tree of dictionaries (based on locations). For example:

```
{"name": "global", "children": [
    {"name": "module1", "children": [ 
        {"name": "submodule1", "children": [
            {"name": "function1", "data": "some data"},
            {"name": "func2", "data": "data again"},
            {"name": "func3", "data": "data"}
            ]},
        {"name": "func1", "data": "other data"}
        ]
     },
    {"name": "module2", "children": [{"name": "func3", "data": "data"}]},
    {"name": "module4", "children": [
        {"name": "submodule1", "children": [{"name": "func3", "data": "data"}]},
        {"name": "submodule2", "data": "da_ta", "children": [{"name": "func4", "data": "daata"}]}
    ]}
] }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "do my (home)work problem for me" question with no code presented by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first solution is similar to Reximus's answer, an interative solution.  Note the tree is rooted at a node named root, allowing multiple top-level namespaces:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pprint

from_this = [
        ("global.module1.submodule1.function1", "some data"),
        ("global.module1.func1", "other data"),
        ("global.module1.submodule1.func2", "data again"),
        ("global.module1.submodule1.func3", "data"),
        ("global.module2.func3", "data"),
        ("global.module4.submodule1.func3", "data"),
        ("global.module4.submodule2.func4", "daata"),
        ("global.module4.submodule2", "da_ta")
]


def make_node():
    d = {
         "name": "",
         "data": "",
         "children": []
         }
    return d

path_sep = "."
tree = make_node()
tree["name"] = "root"
for path, data in from_this:
    current = tree
    path_list = path.split(path_sep)
    for name in path_list:
        next_node = None
        for child in current["children"]:
            if child["name"] == name:
                next_node = child
                break
        if next_node is None:
            n = make_node()
            n["name"] = name
            current["children"].append(n)
            current = n
        else:
            current = next_node
    current["data"] = data
pprint.pprint(tree, indent=1)
```

But perhaps using recursion is the more "idiomatic" way to do any tree-related problem:

```
def insert(path, data, node):
    if len(path) == 0:
        node["data"] = data
        return
    for child in node["children"]:
        if child["name"] == path[0]:
            insert(path[1:], data, child)
            return
    child = make_node()
    child["name"] = path[0]
    node["children"].append(child)
    insert(path[1:], data, child)

tree = make_node()
tree["name"] = "root"
for path, data in from_this:
    insert(path.split(path_sep), data, tree)
pprint.pprint(tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. I didn't optimize it but I think it should be reasonably efficient and use constant memory.

```
def process(entries):
    root = {'name': None}
    for entry in entries:
        node = root
        for name in entry[0].split('.'):
            try:
                node = next(child for child in node['children'] if child['name'] == name)
            except KeyError:
                node['children'] = [{'name': name}]
                node = node['children'][-1]
            except StopIteration:
                node['children'].append({'name': name})
                node = node['children'][-1]
        node['data'] = entry[1]
    return root
```

Note that the return value will be the root of the tree and will look like `{'name': None, 'children': [ ... ]}` because there could be more than one top-level namespace. In the example you gave there is only one top-level namespace `global` but that might not be true in general.

*Example:* Using the sample data `from_this`

```
>>> pprint(process(from_this))
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'data': 'some data',
                                                         'name': 'function1'},
                                                        {'data': 'data again',
                                                         'name': 'func2'},
                                                        {'data': 'data',
                                                         'name': 'func3'}],
                                           'name': 'submodule1'},
                                          {'data': 'other data',
                                           'name': 'func1'}],
                             'name': 'module1'},
                            {'children': [{'data': 'data',
                                           'name': 'func3'}],
                             'name': 'module2'},
                            {'children': [{'children': [{'data': 'data',
                                                         'name': 'func3'}],
                                           'name': 'submodule1'},
                                          {'children': [{'data': 'daata',
                                                         'name': 'func4'}],
                                           'data': 'da_ta',
                                           'name': 'submodule2'}],
                             'name': 'module4'}],
               'name': 'global'}],
 'name': None}
```